# Angular 4 Karma Unit Testing, not detecting the tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to introduce unit testing to my Angular 4 project. I am using Karma for it. I have done the configuration. It shows a connected screen. But it shows not tests! I have one test under `src/app/` directory.

This error appears in console.

```
{
   "originalErr": {
     "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
       "type": "microTask",
       "state": "notScheduled",
       "source": "Promise.then",
       "zone": "<root>",
       "cancelFn": null,
       "runCount": 0
     }
   },
   "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
     "type": "microTask",
     "state": "notScheduled",
     "source": "Promise.then",
     "zone": "<root>",
     "cancelFn": null,
     "runCount": 0
   }
}
```

1st.spec.ts

```
describe('1st tests', () => {
  it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});
```

karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {

  var appBase    = 'src/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appAssets  = '/base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

  // Testing helpers (optional) are conventionally in a folder called `testing`
  var testingBase    = 'src/testing/'; // transpiled test JS and map files
  var testingSrcBase = 'src/testing/'; // test source TS files

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
    ],

    client: {
      builtPaths: [appBase, testingBase], // add more spec base paths as needed
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },

    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      { pattern: appBase + '/systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: appBase + '/systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false },
      'karma-test-shim.js', // optionally extend SystemJS mapping e.g., with barrels

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },


      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: testingSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for modules fetched by SystemJS
      '/base/src/node_modules/': '/base/node_modules/'
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

Karma Connection Screen:
[image]
Any lead to help, will be helpful.

Comment: What does your karma.config look like?

Comment: @DavidL I have added the file!